# WinError 10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

Tags: python, websocket, timeout, codeblocks

Well this is regarding the time out error. Sometimes i get "Connection is already closed". and sometimes i get "[WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" i have no clue what to do. If someone knows this answer please let me know. I know i can use asyncio but i would like to know any solution in this websocket client?
Websocket client closes my connection due to ping pong issue i guess..

```
import websocket
import json
import logging
import initialization
import products_report
import datetime
import time

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread


ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%M')

logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.INFO)

with open('get_config.json') as f:
    bootUp = json.load(f)


def add_error(msg, boolean, code, string, data):
    msg['msgType'] = 'RESULT'
    msg['output'] = {
        'success': boolean,
        'errors': {
            "code": code,
            "msg": string,
            "data": data
        }
    }

    return msg


def add_success(msg, boolean, data):
    msg['msgType'] = 'RESULT'
    msg['output'] = {
        'success': boolean,
        'data': data
    }
    return msg


class Camera:

    def __init__(self):
        logging.info(self)

    def initialize(self, socket, msg):
        global region_init
        region_init = initialization.initial(socket, msg)
        return region_init

    def report_products(self, socket, msg): # Once it enters this loop it shows a time out error because this loop takes 3-4 seconds to compile.
        products_report.products_reporting(socket, msg, region_init)


class MySocket:

    header = {
        'Authorization': 'xxxxxx'}

    def __init__(self):
        self.camera = Camera()
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("www.adfghbkjhbcdfjh.com",
                                         on_message=self.on_message,
                                         header=self.header,
                                         on_error=self.on_error,
                                         on_close=self.on_close)
        self.ws.on_open = self.on_open
        MySocket.run_forever(self)

    def run_forever(self, sockopt=None, sslopt=None,
                    ping_interval=0, ping_timeout=None,
                    http_proxy_host=None, http_proxy_port=None,
                    http_no_proxy=None, http_proxy_auth=None,
                    skip_utf8_validation=False,
                    host=None, origin=None):

        self.ws.run_forever(ping_interval=70, ping_timeout=10)

    def on_message(self, message):
        msg = json.loads(message)
        logging.info(msg)

        if msg["event"] == "FT_CAM_INITIALIZE":
            say = add_success(msg, True, None)
            logging.info(say)
            self.update(say)

        elif msg['event'] == "FT_CAM_START_CAMERA":
            self.camera.initialize(self, message)

        elif msg["event"] == "FT_CAM_REPORT_PRODUCTS":
            self.camera.report_products(self, message)

    def on_error(self, error):
        print(error)

    def on_close(self):
        print("### closed ###")

    def on_open(self):
        def run(*args):
            logging.info(bootUp)

            self.ws.send(json.dumps(bootUp))

        print("thread terminating...")

        thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

    def update(self, msg):
        print(msg)
        print('Sent message')
        self.ws.send(json.dumps(msg))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MySocket()
```

connection should not terminate